# Change title of segmented control with edit button?

Tags: iphone, xcode, edit, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to have an Edit barButtonItem, when pressed I want to be able to select a segmented control and edit the segment title I select and save it. Is this possible?

Comment: This should be possible by detecting the event, then doing something like bringing up a UITextField.  Then on exit of the UITextField using the UISegmentedControl' setTitle:forSegmentAtIndex: method.

Comment: Just added an example with actual working code from an app that I have, obviously I don't need this functionality, but it was a good place for me to begin from.  Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me some time to come up with the example, but here it is!!!

Here is what is in my UIViewController header file:

```
@interface optionsViewController : UIViewController <UIPopoverControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *       centerAreaSizeSelector;

    // Added to support this example
    UISegmentedControl * controlBeingEdited;
    unsigned int segmentBeingEdited;
}

-(IBAction)centerAreaSizeSelector:(id)sender;
@end
```

Obviously my UISegmented control and its action item were connect in Interface Builder.

You must implement the action item for your segmented control here is mine

```
-(IBAction)centerAreaSizeSelector:(id)sender{
    // These are zero Based Reads from the selectors
    unsigned char centerAreaSizeSelection = centerAreaSizeSelector.selectedSegmentIndex;

    // Here we instantiate a NEW invisible UITextField to bring up the keyboard.
    UITextField * textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:textField];
    textField.hidden = YES;
    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    textField.text = [centerAreaSizeSelector titleForSegmentAtIndex:centerAreaSizeSelection];
    textField.delegate = self;
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];

    // The below variable are defined globally to allow the keyboard delegate routines
    // to know which segmented control and which item within the control to edit
    // My design has multiple UISegmentedControls so this is needed for separation
    controlBeingEdited = centerAreaSizeSelector;  // of type UISegmentedControl
    segmentBeingEdited = centerAreaSizeSelection; // of type unsigned int
}
```

Implement the following 3 UITextFieldDelegate Methods as follows

```
// Implement the keyboard delegate routines
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [textField release];
    controlBeingEdited = nil;
    segmentBeingEdited = 0;
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    NSString * theString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    [controlBeingEdited setTitle:theString forSegmentAtIndex:segmentBeingEdited];

    return YES;
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    [controlBeingEdited setTitle:textField.text forSegmentAtIndex:segmentBeingEdited];
}
```

This implements a key-by-key visible editing of a UISegmentedControl element.

NOTES:
This does not in any way implement the auto-resizing that may be necessary if the text is larger than the space provided by the control.

This also does not implement any form of visible cursor or visible selection code.

This will leave the textfield caret position after the last character in the string.  It will copy the current UISegmentedControl' text into the invisible textfield prior to editing so that you don't lose your copy, although it could easily be edited to clear both prior to editing.

Comment: So this will allow the user to be able to select which title they want to edit, no matter how many UISegmentedControl's I have?

Comment: Yes, essentially.  You will for each UISegmentedControl action, replace the 2 lowest lines I have described with the UISegmentedControl assigned to that action, as well as the actual segment being tapped.  Do this for each control, and this should be robust enough to handle how many ever controls, each with as many ever items within each control!!!  Try it, I have tested this to work :-)

Comment: Getting warning: which is why it's not working I think.

//assigning to ID UITexfield Delegate to incompatable type of MyViewController.

    textField.delegate = self;

Comment: So when you say "replace the 2 lowest lines I have described with the UISegmentedControl assigned to that action", you mean replacing "controlBeingEdited" with my Control name? Correct?

Comment: yep! Also I assumed your segmented control would be on the view being controlled within a UIViewController!

Comment: Yes it is. Ok I got it to edit, however it only edits segment title 1, not 0 or 2 or 3 when im clicking on the specific segment in the same segmentedControl. Am I needing to add something? And I guess the warning is ok?

Comment: Well....  you didn't exactly ask that in you question! Warning probably means that you haunt defined you UIViewController with UITextFieldDelegate.  As far as item 0, the UISegmentedControl object only responds when tapping a not-currently selected item!

Comment: Sorry I figured that was assumed that you would want to edit any segments in the segmented controller.
FlipsideViewController : UIViewController{
    id <metricFlipsideViewControllerDelegate, UIPopoverControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate> delegate;

Comment: Oh I see, I can just add some code to make the segments unselected when hitting the edit button. Then they have to select it. Got it!

Comment: OK, if you don't begin with one selected, then ALL will work for text title editing.  Im assuming you want to begin with one selected, and be able to edit the currently selected?  If this is the case, then the only way beyond what I have already provided is to emulate your own functionality using UIButtons and your own meta data backing the button array. Alternatively you could use a momentary push based UISegmentedControl, but it wouldn't ever look like one was selected.

Comment: Yes I will want to have one selected, but once the edit button is pressed, I would want none to be selected. Well, couldn't I call something like myUISegmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex = nil;    ?? That doesn't seem to be working tho.

Comment: Use -1 in myUISegmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex to turn off all selections.  Use the property momentary to set whether you want them to be non-selectable momentary push buttons with YES or NO.

Comment: Really????  That is straight from the APPLE docs LOL.  Try setting in your interface builder file instead, that worked for me!!!